# Como puedo modificar un numero de html mediante javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Soy realmente nuevo en el desarrollo web, y estoy intentando hacer un sistema de monedas, pero no puedo hacer que el texto que aparece en el html pueda ser modificado y mostrado en la pantalla por medio de js.

Hice esto que obviamente esta mal, pero bueno, disculpen y gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La mayoria de etiquetas html van dentro de < y >... `<p>Texto</p>` y el elemento `class` hace referencia a una clase de .css, mejor usa `id="balance"` y lo llamas con `.getElementById('balance')` porque puedes tener muchas veces esa clase en tu html, pero solo un ID por html. Ademas, esto es básico, creo que te falta el toque de investigar, no es del otro mundo

Comment: Si tuve que quitarle < y > al texto de la pregunta porque se eliminaba sino.

Hice lo que me dijiste de hacerlo con id pero no me deja.
No puedo cambiar con innerHTML, nose si hay alguna forma mejor, yo solo quiero que mi texto de html que dice "0" lo pueda cambiar al numero que quiera por medio de js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cuando utilizas getElementsByClassName, esto devuelve un array, es decir una lista de los elementos que tienen asignada esa clase, entonces para que funcione debes acceder a la posición deseada del array, por ejemplo podrías hacer algo así si es un único elemento.

**HTML**

```
<p class="balance"></p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
let moneda = document.getElementsByClassName("balance"); 
moneda[0].innerHTML = "1";
```

---

Otra forma de hacerlo es por su id de la siguiente manera

**HTML**

```
<p id="balance"></p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
let moneda = document.getElementById("balance"); 
moneda.innerHTML = "1";
```

---

**En ninguno de los anteriores casos se pone el "." ni el "#" antes de la clase o ID.**

---

Otra forma de resolverlo es con el uso de querySelector, quedaría algo así:

**En caso de usar una clase:**

```
let moneda = document.querySelector(".balance"); moneda.innerHTML = "1";
```

**En caso de usar un Id:**

```
let moneda = document.querySelector("#balance"); moneda.innerHTML = "1";
```

En este caso si debes especificar "." o "#" antes del nombre de clase o Id, en el caso del Id buscará el único elemento con dicho Id (esto es porque el identificador es único, no deben existir 2 elementos con el mismo id en un mismo html).
En el caso de la clase, buscará el primer elemento que tenga dicha clase, si hay más los ignorará.

Si deseas seleccionar varios elementos nuevamente podrías utilizar el getElementsByClassName o el querySelectorAll, ambos te retornarían un array y recorriendo ese array puedes hacer lo que desees con los valores.

Comment: Muchas gracias tambien por tomarte el tiempo de ayudarme, hice y probe lo que me dijiste pero sigue sin funcionarme, ademas me da este error de js:
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
    at js.js:4:18

Comment: podrías pasar el código completo para ver donde puede estar el problema?, edita tu pregunta, mientras más información des más fácil es para la comunidad ayudarte.

Comment: Ahi hice medio como un collage

Comment: El código está perfecto, verifica que no tengas otro elemento en el html con clase "balance" y q otra línea de js no pueda estar molestando, quizás borra o comenta lo anterior o posterior, para probar.
También podrías hacer un console.log de moneda después de donde haces el getElementsByClassName para ver si realmente captura algo. Verifica también q no esté haciendo referencia a otro script y prueba 
 cerrar y volver a abrir la página. Asegurate de q no tienes archivos sin guardar en el editor, si es VSC, aparece un punto blanco al costado de la pestaña con el nombre del archivo..

Comment: Lo hice pero sigue sin funcionar, nose que puede estar pasanado, gracias igualmente!

Comment: Agregué algunas cosas al comentario, hay varias cosas para chequear..

Comment: Sabes lo que fue, que el <script src="js.js"></script> que es lo que use para concatenar mi js a mi html estaba antes que la creación del <p class="balance">0</p> . Mi pregunta ahora ya que se soluciono esto es.. En que parte es mejor poner el <script? al final?

Comment: En general se pone el script al final, justo antes de cerrar la etiqueta Body, a no ser casos puntuales, donde deseas que se carguen primero los Scripts, un caso podría ser el Script de Google Analytics que sugieren primero cargar el Script y luego el resto para que las estadísticas sean mejores.

Comment: Claro! No tenia ni idea! jaja, hace 2 meses que empecé con javascript hay miles de cosas que no tengo ni idea, muchas gracias de nuevo por tu tiempo! Te mando un abrazo!

Comment: A las órdenes, lo mejor de este mundillo del desarrollo es que es un mundo colaborativo, siempre que pueda será un placer. Hasta la próxima, abrazo!